# What can cause my iis to not allow browsing directory?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, iis, iis-7

im trying to set-up and entity frameWork that gonna use sql-server 2008 for genarating the database with the code-first approche .... So im just starting by creating 2 class that contain some proprieties for a testing it ... (with asp.net):

make the class Articles :

```
public class Articles
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string desc{ get; set; }
  public decimal price { get; set; }

  public Articles()
    {

    }
}
```

make the class Stores :

```
public class Stores
{

  int ID { get; set; }
  String Name { get; set; }
  List<Articles> Elements { get; set; }

    public Stores()
    {

    }
}
```

Afther making the Context class  :

```
public class dbSroreContext : DbContext
{

  public DbSet<Stores> Stores { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Articles> Articles { get; set; }

    public dbSroreContext()
    {

    }
```

}

ok then im putting the connection string in my web.config file :

```
<configuration>


  <configSections>

    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->


  </configSections>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server.;"
         name="dbSroreContext"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

so far I'm trying to enable my directory browser in my IIS but no result ....

```
Error : The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

Comment: Why don't you enable directory browsing as the error message suggests? Here are few tips http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/directorybrowse

Comment: allready did it -_- it doing nothing for me :P

Comment: Directory browsing has nothing to do with the code you were trying to build -- the problem is you've got some EF classes but no web app.

Answer (score 0):

OK finaly i got the best solution i tink! I have more then one server on my pc ... and that was messing up with server enable the browsing directory stuff! So the best thing i can do i tink is to enable it from the website level :

```
 <system.webServer>
   <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

add this in the web.config file and it should be fine! I hope it can help some other :D ty for trying to help! :D